# Concatenate rows based on row comparisons using LINQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I tried doing this in SQL for about a month now, but I think it might be easier to do it with .NET linq.

The basics are as follows:

The query is supposed to return data from a date range, and return a concatenated list of player names and player times.

The concatenation would ONLY occur if the `playEnd` was within 30 minutes of the next players `playStart`.

So if I have data like this:

```
Name        PlayDate         PlayStart      PlayEnd
----------------------------------------------------
player1 |   10/8/2018    |   08:00:00   |   09:00:00
player2 |   10/8/2018    |   09:10:00   |   10:10:00
player3 |   10/9/2018    |   10:40:00   |   11:30:00
player4 |   10/11/2018   |   08:30:00   |   08:37:00
player5 |   10/11/2018   |   08:40:00   |   08:50:00  
player6 |   10/12/2018   |   09:00:00   |   09:45:00
player7 |   10/12/2018   |   09:50:00   |   10:10:00
player8 |   10/12/2018   |   10:30:00   |   12:20:00
```

- `player1` and `player2` play times would be concatenated together like: `player1`, `player2 = 8:00:00 - 10:10:00 for 10/8/2018`
- `player3` would just be: `player3 = 10:40:00 - 11:30:00 for 10/9/2018`
- `player4` and `player5` play times would be concatenated like: `player4`, `player5 = 08:30:00 - 08:50:00 for 10/11/2018`
- `player6` and `player7` and `player8` play times would be concatenated like: `player6`, `player7`, `player8 = 09:00:00 - 12:20:00 for 10/12/2018`

I've tried modifying the query below in many ways, but I just don't know how to compare one row of data with the next and then combine the two (or more) if needed.

```
        var query = from pl in players
                            select new PlaySession
                            {
                                Name = pl.Name,
                                PlayDate = pl.PlayDate,
                                PlayStart = pl.PlayStartTime,
                                PlayEnd = pl.PlayEndTime
                            };

            var grouped = query
                        .OrderBy(r => r.Name)
                        .ThenBy(r => r.PlayDate)
                        .ThenBy(r => r.PlayStart)
```

Now this is where I get confused:

I need to figure out the following:

- how to compare `PlayDates` of the various rows to make sure that they are the same date, like this:   `row1.PlayDate == row2.PlayDate`
- how to compare one rows `PlayEnd` with the next rows `PlayStart`, something like this:    `row2.PlayStart - row1.PlayEnd < 30 minutes`

Is there a way to compare values across rows using LINQ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per as I am concern, thing should be like as follows:

```
List<ViewModel> playersGroupList =  Players.GroupBy(p => p.PlayDate).Select(group => new ViewModel
                {
                    PlayDate = group.Key,
                    Names = String.Join("-", group.Select(g => g.Name).ToArray()),
                    PlayDuration = group.Select(g => g.PlayStart).First() + "-" + group.Select(g => g.PlayEnd).Last()
                }).ToList();
```

And here `ViewModel` is as follows:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public string PlayDate {get set;}
   public string Names {get set;}
   public string PlayDuration {get set;}
}
```

Note: Some adjudgement may be needed to fulfill your point to point requirement but actual implementation should be as shown.

Comment: What is ViewModel?  I'm trying to create an IEnumerable of PlaySession class so that I can return it from my controller like this: return View(playersGroupList);Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I have updated the my answer . Here `ViewModel ` is a DTO for mapping the projected object.

Comment: All looks good except this...group.Select(g => g.PlayStart).Last()  I'm getting an Invalid Initializer Member Declarator error?  Never seen that before

Comment: Let me check please!

Comment: Please give a try with `group.Select(g => g.PlayStart).ToList().First()` and `group.Select(g => g.PlayEnd).ToList().Last()` and let me know!

Comment: Did `.ToList().First()` and `.ToList().Last()` make the trick?

Comment: It was actually the missing "+" symbol. :)

Comment: So we can remove the .ToList()! Okay?

Comment: One thing I just noticed, is that it doesn't take into account this requirement: The concatenation would ONLY occur if the playEnd was within 30 minutes of the next players playStart.

Comment: Okay! I shall take a look onto it.